# Первое использование метода ReadlLine в другой кодировке C#

Tags: c#, кодировка

Вот код

```
public void EnterNames(int index)
{
    string SearchPng = "preview.png";
    string[] ModDir2;
    string[] PngDir2;
    List<string> ModDir = new List<string>();
    List<string> PngDir = new List<string>();
    GetAllFiles(rootDirectory, SearchExp, ModDir);
    ModDir2 = ModDir.ToArray();

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ModDir2[index], Encoding.Default);
    label4.Text = reader.ReadLine();
    label5.Text = reader.ReadLine();
    label6.Text = reader.ReadLine();
    GetAllFiles(rootDirectory, SearchPng, PngDir);
    PngDir2 = PngDir.ToArray();
    pictureBox1.Load(PngDir2[index]);
```

Первый результат описания мода, как я понял в другой кодировке, вот  [скрин](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgq46.png)
в то время как остальные 2 написаны нормальным текстом(и русский, и английский язык) В чем проблема?
P.S Метод `GetAllFiles()` ищет все файлы с нужным расширением(или именем) И записывает их в коллекцию, из которой записывается в массив, каждый индекс которого является путем к описанию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Каждый текстовый файл на деле содержит текст в какой-то кодировке. Когда вы открываете файл и указываете `Encoding.Default` (то есть, ANSI-кодировку вашей системы), вы можете и не угадать. Если вы укажете неправильную кодировку, из файла прочитаются кракозябры.

Указывайте правильную кодировку, всё прочитается как надо.

Comment: Кстати, вы не закрываете `reader`, и совершенно непонятно, зачем конвертировать `List<string>` в массив.

Comment: А какую кодировку тогда указывать? Например UTF8 не правильно отображает Русский текст

Comment: @STALER: Ну откуда мне знать, в какой кодировке ваш текст? Попробуйте CP-1251 или CP-866, если текст должен быть русским (`Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)` и т. д.)

Comment: По сути данный код является броузером модов, и подразумевает загрузку пользовательских модов, а браузер открывает мета файл с описанием, и выводит все это

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я нашел причину. Видимо Notpead++ меняет кодировку когда я сохраняю документ им.

Comment: @STALER: Пожалуйста! Хорошо, что разобрались!